# MSAL (Java) Rest API Authentication ( Authorization : Bearer Token )

Tags: java, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I'd like to secure a Java Rest API against Azure AD B2C.

I understand that the caller is calling the service using the Authorization header with a value like: Bearer xxx-token

Is that an ID or Access Token ?

What are the steps the service should take to ensure this is a valid token? Java code using MSAL4J would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Access token is always the one your API should receive. The ID token is for the app that requested authentication.

Answer (score 3):

MSAL4J is for acquiring tokens so clients can access protected resources, not for validating tokens in your API.

Your API should be receiving an access token in the authorization header. This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens) explains what claims might be included in the access token and how to validate them.

Microsoft does not provide a Java library for this validation at the moment, but there are many third-party open source libraries that provide this functionality. For example, you can use [jjwt](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt)

Comment: Very accurate answer, thanks. Note that for the JWK part, you need yet another library as jjwt cant do that, like auth0 jwks-rsa

Comment: @phil294 JJWT should be able to handle it. I've seeing this question quite a bit, so I put together a brief tutorial: https://sgonzal.com/2020/03/28/jwt-validation.html

Comment: Nice article, it will be helpful to future people. By "jjwt cant do [jwk]", I meant the key lookup itself, so you dont have to do the url fetching. This helps reducing the code to something like [this](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt/issues/236#issuecomment-341519715)

Comment: Oh yes, you are right, JJWT does not handle fetching the keys.

Comment: @sgonzalez any chance your tutorial be public again pls?

Comment: @SilverFox Yes it should still be public, the URL is https://sgonzal.com/2020/04/06/jwt-validation.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this [MSAL4J B2C sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-webapp/tree/master/msal-b2c-web-sample), which calls a protected web api?

[Here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-webapp/blob/master/msal-b2c-web-sample/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/msalwebsample/AuthPageController.java#L90) in the sample is where it's including the access token, from when the user signed-in and appending it to the header as a Bearer token. Then a middleware library, for example [Spring Security](https://spring.io/projects/spring-security) for java, will validate the token.

```java
private String callB2CApi(String accessToken){
   RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

   HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(null, headers);

    String result = restTemplate.exchange(authHelper.configuration.api, HttpMethod.GET,
                entity, String.class).getBody();

     return new Date() + result;
}
```

Here's more [information on using MSAL4J](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-call-api-app-configuration?tabs=java) to create a web app which signs-in users and then calls a protected web api. More [code samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-call-api-call-api?tabs=java) for calling a protected web api.

Here's an [overview of the b2c token types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tokens-overview#token-types). The idToken contains the claims about the user and the access token provides scoped permission to your web api.

Comment: Thank you for the calling part. But the question is about the actual Java code validating the access token: I'm not using at all String Security.